# How can I find the default lead creator in Apex?

Tags: apex

In a controller class for a VF form I would like to query the id of the user who was set as the default lead creator in the web-to-lead settings.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm

Unfortunately Web to lead is not exposed through even metadata API that we can use in apex through WSDL parsing.

An alternative can be maintain a label or custom setting and train the administrator of your organisation to keep custom setting and web to lead setting in sync(May be only Default owner in your case)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and workaround. Since you can't (easily) save the user Id in a custom setting, I am going for a custom checkbox field on the user object called "Main peanut" and the org admin will just have to make sure that only the default lead creator has this checked. Messy, but workable.

Answer (score 2):

It will be very hacky but maybe you could learn from [Organization](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) object the `LastWebToLeadDate`. This plus query on Lead's field history (assuming you're tracking changes of owner field)?

This could be easily foiled though - for example if assignment rules were used or by some fluke web2lead and normal lead were created at same time.