# Apex Test class for web-to-lead creation without OwnerId

Tags: unit-test, web2lead, insert

I need to create an Apex test class for a Lead Apex Trigger that handles "before insert" of the web-to-lead inserts of Lead records that DON'T have OwnerId at the "before insert" time.
Assigning of OwnerId is hadnled by the trigger.

How can I create a test class method that simulates this by inserting Leads with OwnerId = null?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a Lead with a `null` OwnerId, through Web-to-Lead, or in Apex. [`Lead.OwnerId` is `defaultedOnCreate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm), and so will be set [when the object is created](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/required_fields.htm), before any triggers are run.

Unless set through a hidden form field (which is a bad idea anyway, as you'd be putting a User Id in public web forms), `Lead.OwnerId` will be set to the Default Lead Creator specified in Web-to-Lead settings. You could set that to a user that should *never* own Leads, and then base your trigger logic on that user owning the Lead. Or you could set another field on Lead with a hidden form field, and base your trigger logic on that.

Comment: great minds think alike (finally - hat tip to you for pointing out my epistemic arrogance)

Answer (score 1):

At beforeInsert time, the sobject's OwnerId field is always populated in Trigger.new.  Thus, you need to change your code to test for OwnerID = The default lead owner (see `Setup | Lead Settings` and change the OwnerId accordingly. *The default lead owner is used for W2L.*

Unfortunately, LeadSettings is not available in the Metadata API (V46) as it is [an unsupported type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) so you can't really robustify your code to be tolerant of any settings value.

The workaround hacks are discussed here in [this SFSE Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24811/how-can-i-find-the-default-lead-creator-in-apex). As such, for coding and testing, you may need to use custom settings, custom metadata, or custom labels to maintain an unsync'ed copy of the default lead owner

A better workaround is to use LeadSource='Web' as your clue that it is a W2L (or some other field you set ONLY on your W2L form.